# filtering input to only numbers. C

Tags: c, input, limiting

Here's a basic question:

How can I take the input from a user and only accept numbers?
I know I need to use this start:

```
    do{
    ch=getchar();
     }while (ch != '\n');
```

But I know it's not enough. This will block every input, including numbers, so I need to break when input is number. 
also how do I break not after the first digit of the number?

I tried looking this up with no luck.

thanks!

Comment: The "break" part is not clear. What do you want to do if the input is not a number?

Comment: One option (if input is limited to ASCII characters) is to cast `ch` to an integer and then check the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/). Numbers will fall between 48 and 57.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline `ch` should be `int` anyway, to match the return value from `getchar` so no need to cast. And no need to assume ASCII, just use the range `'0'` to `'9'` which are also `int` values. The code will be clearer too.

Comment: @WeatherVane Whoops, good catch. I mentioned the ASCII tables because this has the feel of anassignment and that was a 'learning outcome' for a similar project I once encountered.

Answer (score 3):

When you need to perform error checking, do different things based on the input, etc., it's best to read user input line by line and process each line as you see fit.

```
// Make it large enough for your needs.
#define LINE_LENGTH 200

char line[LINE_LENGTH];

// Keep reding lines of text until there is nothing to read.
while ( fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL )
{
   // Process contents of line.
}
```

If you expect to see only one number per line, you can use `sscanf` to extract numbers from each line.

```
while ( fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL )
{
   int num;
   if ( sscanf(line, "%d", &num) == 1 )
   {
      // Got a number. Use it.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The probably easiest way to read in a number is using `scanf`:

```
int number;
if (scanf("%d",&number) == 1) {
  printf("successfully read number %d\n",number);
} else {
  printf("not a number.\n");
}
```

It skips leading white spaces and then takes characters from `stdin` as long as these match an integral number format. Note that you still might have to press "enter" before your program will proceed, because the operating system might buffer the input (beyond your control).

Note that a `ch=getchar()` will take also the first non-digit value from `stdin`, which can then not be consumed by any further access to `stdin` anymore. `scanf`, in contrast, keeps this character in the buffer for later use.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the input is some value between `'0'` and `'9'`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    char str[32];
    int ch;

    while (len < sizeof(str) - 1) {
        ch = getchar();
        if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')) {
            str[len++] = (char)ch;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    str[len] = '\0';
    puts(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple, nice and neat solution:), I used to solve similar questions when I started programming, this will let you only input numbers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char ch;
  do{
    ch=getchar();
   }while (!(ch>=48 && ch<=57));
printf("yay,we got a number : %c !",ch);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: that is a nice elegant solution! maybe you can help me take it one step further. do you mind contacting me through e-mail? i see this site doesn't support messaging. omerben.g@gmail.com

Comment: Okay I will but tomorrow cuz i don't have my laptop now i left it at work , and please accept and upvote my solution if you liked it :)